# UK Pension Annual Allowance and Carry Forward

Tags: pension, pension-sipp

If i have a pension and for the last 3 years didn't make any contributions. Then, this current tax year i make the full £60k contribution as per the annual allowance. Next year, what would my maximum contribution be - the way i see it there are 2 possibilities.

option 1
year 1 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 2 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 3 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 4 - 60k contribution
year 5 - max contribiton = 60k + 40 (year 2) + 40 (year 3) = total 140k

option 2
year 1 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 2 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 3 - 0 contribution - 40k not used
year 4 - 60k contribution (allocated as 40 to year 1 and 20 to year 2)
year 5 - max contribiton = 60k + 20 (year 2) + 40 (year 3) + 60 (year 4) = total 180k

it all depends on how current year contributions are treated. do they fill the current years  allowance before flowing down to previous years. or do current year contributions start by filling gaps in the previous 3 years (oldest first).

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They fill the current years' allowance before flowing down to previous years (oldest first).

References:

The [general UK government page](https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-your-private-pension/annual-allowance):

> **If you use all of your annual allowance for the current tax year**
>
> You might be able to carry over any annual allowance you did not use from the previous 3 tax years.

This [technical manual from HMRC](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/pensions-tax-manual/ptm055100) goes into a lot of detail and is clear that in all cases:

> The annual allowance for the current tax year is used first.

Comment: It seems to me that the two "How available annual allowance is used up" sections that are at the end of the technical manual you cite are _exactly_ the rules that OP is after...

Comment: @AakashM oh yes, it does explicitly state "The annual allowance for the current tax year is used first.", thanks.